# Delete files inside a folder, but not delete folders

Tags: python, directory

How do I delete all the files in a folder, except the folders inside?

I have a folder named `here`.

And i have 10 folders inside `here` named 1 to 10, and different files that are not folders.

How i can only delete that files?

I try but i can only delete all.

yeha, i try

```
path = 'C:\\teste' 
imagesToTrain = os.listdir(path) 
for f in imagesToTrain: 
     if not os.path.isdir(f): 
         os.remove(f)
```

but dont find the file

Comment: Please post what you tried, and why you think it should be solving your problem.

Comment: What did you try? Post your code. Presumably all your code lacks is a `if f.isfile():` or `if not os.path.isdir(p)` somewhere.

Comment: yeha, i try path = 'C:\\teste'

imagesToTrain = os.listdir(path)

print(imagesToTrain)

for f in imagesToTrain:
    if not os.path.isdir(f):
        os.remove(f)

but dont find the file

Comment: Please add the code to your question be editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand really well your problem but I here is a code I made with the two possible options:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import rmtree

def delete_folders(path: Path):
    """
    Delete all folders in a folder.
    """
    for folder in path.glob('*'):
        if folder.is_dir():
            rmtree(folder)

def delete_files(path: Path):
    """
    Delete all files in a folder.
    """
    for file in path.glob('*'):
        if file.is_file():
            file.unlink()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder_path = Path('/path/to/folder/')
    # This is for deleting only the folders inside folder_path.
    delete_folders(folder_path)
    # This is for delte only the files inside folder_path.
    delete_files(folder_path)
```

Comment: the second fucntion tells me "'str' object has no attribute 'glob'"

Comment: Yeah because you need to set the path like this:
`folder_path = Path('/path/to/folder/')`